# A question about the proof of the transpose of the product being equal to the product of the transpose in reverse order.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A, B$ be matrices of a size such that $AB$ is defined. Then $(AB)^t = B^t A^t$ where $t$ denotes the transpose.

Proof:

Let $A = (a_{ij})$ and $B = (b_{jk})$. Then $AB = C = (c_{ik})$ where

$c_{ik} = a_{i1} b_{1k} + ... + a_{in} b_{nk}$

= $b_{1k} a_{i1} + ... + b_{nk} a_{in}$.

Let $A^t = ('a_{ji}), B^t = ('b_{kj} )$ and $C^t = ('c_{ki})$.

Then $'a_{ji} = a_{ij}, 'b_{kj} = b_{jk}$ and $'c_{ki} = c_{ik}$.

I don't get the last line. Please, explain why that's true. Thanks.

Also, how do I get the second subscript in say, $(a_ij)$ right?

Comment: Braces, `a_{ij}` gives $a_{ij}$.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a year late, but that line you said you don't understand simply follows from the definition of transpose.

A clean proof for $nxn$ matricies would be like this:

Suppose $A=(a_{ij})$ and $B=(b_{ij})$ and $AB=(c_{ij})$. Then $A^T=(a'_{ij})$ where $a'_{ij}=a_{ji}$, and $B^T=(b'_{ij})$ where $b'_{ij}=b_{ji}$.  Now let $(AB)^T=(c'_{ij})$.  We must show $c'_{ij}=c_{ji}$.

For all $i,j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, $c_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^na_{ik}b_{kj}$ and   $c'_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^na'_{ik}b'_{kj}$.

Therefore, $c'_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^na'_{ik}b'_{kj} = \sum_{k=1}^na_{ki}b_{jk} = \sum_{k=1}^nb_{jk}a_{ki} = c_{ji}$.

Therefore $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$.